What is the meaning of $\sum_i K_iK_i^\dagger$ for a quantum channel with Kraus operators $K_i$?
Let a channel $N$ be given in terms of its Kraus operators $K_i$ as
$$N(\rho) = \sum_i K_i\rho K_i^\dagger.$$
Is the sum $\sum_i K_iK_i^\dagger$ a meaningful quantity? I know that $\sum_i K_i K_i^\dagger = I$ for unital channels. But what about more general cases?

Changing $K_i\to K_i^\dagger$ means you implement the adjoint channel, so this could be something like "the trace-preserving-ness of the adjoint channel"

@Pluto I interpreted the question and re-wrote it accordingly. Hope it reflects what you wanted to know.

@DanieleCuomo your edit changed unital to unitary and the question is about $\sum_i K_iK^\dagger_i$ not $\sum_i K_i^\dagger K_i$$. But otherwise, it's what I meant.

Yes, that was a typo that I fixed now. Feel free to make further edits.

Yes, the sum $\sum_iK_iK_i^\dagger$ is (a scalar multiple of) the quantum state output by the channel on the maximally mixed input
\begin{align}
N\left(\frac{I}{d}\right)=\frac{1}{d}\sum_iK_iK_i^\dagger.\tag1
\end{align}
In particular, if $N(I)=I$ then $N$ is said to be $\textit{unital}$$^1$ which implies that its adjoint$^2$ is trace preserving and hence itself a quantum channel.

$^1$ As is observed in the question, all unitary channels are unital. Other examples include depolarizing and dephasing channels. A well-known non-example is the amplitude damping channel.
$^2$ Adjoint $N^\dagger$ of $N$ is the map $N^\dagger(\rho)=\sum_iK_i^\dagger\rho K_i$.
